# Azure Managed Application - reliable way to deploy .NET code to Azure Function

Tags: azure-managed-app

Wonder if anyone can share production experiences regarding safe and reliable way of deploying code to Azure Function within the Azure Managed Application.
I've found an official sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/commercial-marketplace-ama-metering-accelerator/blob/main/function/ama-custom-billing-msi-trigger-with-request-body/arm/mainTemplate.json) that uses WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE setting pointing to the staging storage of the Managed Application based on

```
uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri
```

Is that storage:

1. Secure? By this example absolutely not - it is based on public access as there is no SAS token added. How to achieve SAS token security - lifetime should be maxed out?
2. Persistent? Other words - not ephemeral that will be ultimately deleted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a 'proxy' Function App which you host on a public storage blob. The 'proxy' Azure function is deployed first and takes a URI and personal access token so that it can proxy the request to a private git repo / storage. Next, within your ARM template you can store a Personal Access token which you append to the base URI of this proxy that will return the data for the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE property.

Now, you can pull code from a private git repo via the proxy function app. A fully worked example can be found [here](https://blog.tyang.org/2017/05/19/deploying-arm-templates-with-artifacts-located-in-a-private-github-repository/). This is unfortunately the best solution which was proposed from the support team when I wanted to securely deploy code to an App service. Our team ended up with automating CI/CD pipelines from the Managed Application notification system so that we would push the source code to the App Service/ Function App when it was fully deployed.